# jQuery: vertical news ticker with custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know any jQuery plug-in (or set of plug-ins:) to have a vertical news ticker

like here: http://lifehacker.com/ (on the right of the page)

I.e.

1. Periodically polls data to add it to the top
2. Has a custom-looking auto-hiding scroll-bar
3. On scrolling down requests older data from the server.